# Sequence generator as extension function call fails with "receiver type mismatch"

Tags: generator, kotlin, coroutine

I'm playing around with trying to generate a sequence out of a single `Long` value prepended to a `LongRange`. This works:

```
val seq = buildSequence<Long> {
    yield(2)
    yieldAll(3L..5)
}
```

But trying to generalize it, I can't seem to structure an extension function that I can call successfully:

```
infix fun Long.join(R: LongRange): Sequence<Long> {
    val start = this
    return buildSequence<Long> {
        yield(start)
        yieldAll(R)
    }
}
```

When I attempt to call it:

```
(2 join 3..5).forEach { /* do something */ }
```

I get

> Error:(26, 20) Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
>   public infix fun Long.join(R: LongRange): Sequence defined in main.kotlin

It seems as though the compiler recognizes that the signature of the function is *close* to what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm clearly fuzzy on what "receiver type mismatch" means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *'receiver type mismatch'* error means that what is [passed as a receiver to the extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) (i.e. what it is called on) does not correspond to the declared receiver type.

Kotlin, unlike Java, [**doesn't promote** numbers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions) to broader numeric types, and you have to use [`Long` literals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#literal-constants) in your code where a `Long` is expected:

```
(2L join 3L..5).forEach { /* do something */ }
```

<sup>Here, using `2` as a receiver is not an option because a `Long` is expected. But in `3L..5` using `5` is OK because there is a [`Long.rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/range-to.html) overload that accepts an `Int` and returns a `LongRange`.</sup>

---

The only exception when **there is** an automatic promotion is when you assign an `Int` literal into a variable of another integral type and when you pass an `Int` literal as an argument to a function that expects another integral type (as said above, it doesn't work with receivers).

```
val a: Long = 5 // OK

fun f(l: Long) { }
f(5)            // OK

val b = 5
val c: Long = b // Error
f(b)            // Error
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The compiler kind of hosed me here -- if it had just said something like "no such function join for type Int" and not shown me the function it was trying to match, I probably would have figured that out. 

I assume this means I could also add a corresponding extension for Int as a possible solution.